# Can we prevent EF reverse engineer from removing trailing 's' from table name

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, reverse-engineering

Table name: TableStatus  The tool produces TableStatu with a variable name of TableStatus.  For others, TablePerson it creates TablePerson with variable name TablePersons.  With Code First you can remove the pluralizations.   I found some snippets for both the Entity.tt and Context.tt to remove/add pluralization when you reverse engineer, but neither seem to have any affect on the output classes and DbContext DbSet names.  It may be something simple, but I don't see it.

Comment: They are planning on a fix for this. Details http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/446

Answer (score -1):

When you do a database-first model, there is an option to pluralize/singularize entity names.  Turn this off and it should solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but we are doing Code First (actually Code Second) where you reverse engineer an existing database to Model classes via the entity framework power tools.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Table attribute to specify the table name.

```
[Table("account", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned, we are going code to db, we are reverse engineering from db to poco.  Want to prevent the rev eng from altering the table names at all.

Comment: I guess my point was that you can specify the physical table name in the Table("TableStatus") attribute instead of letting Entity Framework determine what it should be. I use this all the time when I'm starting with an existing database and adding in EF after.